# In Firefox, how to migrate certificates (from cert8.db on XP) and add it to another cert8.db on win7

Tags: firefox

I have a use case where, I need to move the certificates stored in Firefox to another machine.

On my Windows XP source machine, I have 2 certificates (say cert-a, cert-b) which are stored as part of the Firefox 4.0 browser (I assume certificates are stored in `cert8.db`).

On my Windows 7 destination machine, I have 2 new certificates (say cert-c and cert-d) which are stored in Firefox 12.0.

I need to move cert-a and cert-b to the destination machine.  Which means, I need to move the cert8.db file from Windows XP to Windows 7 so that I get the certificates. By doing so, I will lose cert-c and cert-d which was on my destination machine before migration.

What are the steps required to move the certs from the old machine to the new machine while retaining any certs that are already present on the new machine?

Comment: Export the two certificates (they will remain on the old machine). Import the certificates (they will be added to the certificate store on the new machine in addition to the already existing certificates). Don't make it harder than it really is. The import/export is built into Firefox exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

On the source machine go to *Options*->*Advanced*->*Encryption*->*View Certificates* and *Backup* the required certificates. Then on the other machine go the same path but *Import* the certificates. I don't know if there is an easier way, but this way should not be a problem if you have just two certificates in one Firefox profile.

Comment: Can't get any easier than this. And it's highly recommended that you back up any custom certificates by exporting them and save them to a safe location anyway. This saves the worry of having a Firefox profile corrupt and then losing the certificates.